# Mysql delete row where parent does not exist

Tags: mysql

I have a table called items with collumns "itemID" and "parentID" where the parentID is an ID from another row in the table. I want to remove the rows where the parentID-row doesn't exist anymore.

This is what i came up with:

```
DELETE FROM items
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1)
       FROM items as parent
       WHERE items.parentID=parent.itemID)=0
```

But i get the following error: You can't specify target table 'items' for update in FROM clause

**EDIT:** it would be nice if items linking to items removed by this query will also be removed by the query, is this possible in sql or should I code it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using subqueries is inefficent; use left join with [multiple-table syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html):

```
DELETE items 
FROM items
    left join items as parent 
        on items.parentID = parent.itemID
WHERE parent.itemID is NULL
```

multiple-table syntax allows you to specify join in the delete command - so you can join multiple tables and only delete from one. I.e.  `DELETE t1 FROM t1 join t2 ....` will join `t1` and `t2` but only delete the corresponding rows from table `t1`.

As for your question *"it would be nice if items linking to items removed by this query will also be removed by the query, is this possible in sql or should I code it?"*

I think this would end up with cascade - the deleted record could be parent of another record, so delete that one also, but that one could be also parent of another record, so you need to delete it too, etc. etc. I think it is not possible to query all this cascade by a single SQL query.

So I think the easiest solution is to **re-run the above query until no rows are deleted.**

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! I will write a function that reruns until no more items are removed

Answer (score 3):

The query will be

```
DELETE items FROM items 
left join parent 
    on items.parentID = parent.ID
WHERE parent.ID is NULL
```

Comment: will not work, because delete needs to know from which table to delete. You need to use muultiple-table syntax, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this little sorcery...

```
delete from FooTable f1 where f1.parent_id 
         not in (select f2.item_id from FooTable f2);
```

of course this query has a small problem, if you are sharpy you probably noticed, that it might generate new FooRecords without parent (this is, their parent might be deleted during the query execution).

Execute the query multiple times by hand, if you don't need something automated, or place it inside a loop and stop the loop when the number of deleted records is 0.